# Date Calculation improvement

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime

In my program i want to calculate the last day, Last week, Last 3 months etc.

I have tried it with the following code.

My Drop down items are like this:

```
string[] items = { "All", "Last 1 Day", "Last 2 Days", 
"Last 1 Week", "Last 2 Weeks", "Last 1 Month", 
"Last 3 Months", "Last 6 Months", "Last 1 Year" };
```

The Selected Index when i select the drop down:

```
public int _selectedDay = -1;
        public int selectedDay
        {
            get { return _selectedDay; }
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.selectedDay, value);
                dayCalculation(selectedDay);               
            }
        }
```

And the day calculation method:

```
void dayCalculation(int selected)
        {
            switch (selected)
            {
                case 0:
                    //MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (selectedDay));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));                    
                    break;
                case 2:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected Index==>" + (DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yy")));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here i can get expected output. But now i want to simplify/reduce the program lines. Is there any default or simple method to calculate the previous days?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous days"?

Comment: For example if i select Last one day mean it shows Yesterdays Date. If i select Last month mean it will shows Last month date(11/07/2014).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can make it any simpler than what you have. One solution would be not to use 0 through 8 as your posted values but some code, for example:

```
d1, d2, d7, d14, m1, m3, m6, y1
```

And then parse this code to determine what value to subtract from the current date. So for example:

```
d1 --> DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
m3 --> DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
```

It makes your solution more flexible but not simpler.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Ronald. When i select the drop down item it returns the integer value. That's why i use 0 to 8.

Comment: I understand but instead of using integer values you could use something else (like these codes).